# Increase color depth to 16 Bit / reduce banding in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, export, gradient

I use Illustrator to create gradients with the *Freeform Gradient* tool.

When I export a gradient as a PNG, banding is clearly visible. That's why I'd like to increase the color depth to **16 Bit**.

Is that possible? If not, is there another way to **avoid banding** in my final export (besides adding noise afterwards)?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to make illustrator render to 16 bit color.

You can add noise on top of your gradient this makes the gradient look more uniform.